# python matplotlib: how to control the position of the yaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib, position, yaxis

I am generating a set of charts which I will later use in reportlab to create a pdf, and several charts will be aligned on each page.
I want to have the pdf with all y-axis of the charts vertically aligned, and this requires that the y-axis are in the same position in all charts.
The charts have differente scales on the yaxis, so the position of the y-axis varies among charts due to the different y-labels.
How can I fix this? How can I specify the position of the y-axis?
I have tried with tight-layout, subplots_adjust, and add_axes, but all control the padding or the position of the figure or the axes, not the position of the y-axis.

[image: y-axis missaligned charts]

Here the original code, reading data from pandas:

`for i in range (0, len(df_country), 1):

```
CountryISO  = df_country.iloc[i,1]
CountryName = df_country.iloc[i,2]
df_1 = df_data[(df_data.TYPE == 'POP') & (df_data.ISO == CountryISO)]
plt.scatter(df_1.YEAR, df_1.DATA , color = 'm', s = 3.0)
plt.title(CountryName + '; Population vs Time', loc = 'right')
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('population, million')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(1950, 2020)

plt.tight_layout() # this I added later, but still does not work

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.savefig(RootDir + CountryISO + '_POP vs TIME.png', dpi = 600)`
```

It is quite straightforward, I guess, and it does not keep the y-axis aligned, as per the snapshot above.

Comment: Unless you use `tight_layout`/`constrained_layout` or `bbox_inches="tight"`, the axes will be at the same position throughout. So if it isn't, make sure to not use any of the above.

Comment: Thanks, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , but the point is not with the axes by with the y-axis. I have not used your code and the y-axis are not in the same posiiton. And that's why I started looking for a solution.

Comment: We don't know the code you used. Maybe you use one of those implicitely (without knowing). One thing I can tell here is that if you save the figure via `fig.savefig("test.png")` (and not using any of the mentionned commands) the axes will be perfectly aligned.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I think it is quite straightforward, and it does not work. What I now know is that subplots keep the y-axis and x-axis aligned, even if the x/y-labels of teh subplots are much different, so I will use them.

Comment: You need to remove the  line `plt.tight_layout()`, as said earlier.

Comment: I thank your comments, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, but it would be better if you read the messages: the snapshot attached in the question shows the result without the tight_layout, and it is obvious that it does not respect the vertical alignment of the y-axis, which is the point of the question.

Comment: The image in the question shows the output in a jupyter notebook, not the `savefig` output.

Comment: I am sorry, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I leave it to you, but I quite this exchange which seems rather odd to me. Anyhow: the snapshots are from the notebook becasue the results with the saved images are the same: the position of the y-axis is not respected.

Comment: If the results from the saved images show indeed a different distance of the y axis to the left figure edge, that will be due to `tight_layout`, `constrained_layout` or `bbox_inches="tight"` in use. That's all I can say with the information provided. The answer to the question as it stands currently, is then to remove the line `plt.tight_layout()`.